# Why my function always show me the same error?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def formater_un_gobblet(gobblet):
    if gobblet == []:
        return None
    w = [1,2]
    for i in w:
        x = GOBBLET_REPRÉSENTATION[int(i)]
    z = [0,1,2,3]
    for l in z:
        y = x[int(l)]
    gobblet = [x,y]
    return (x,y)
```

This is my Gobblet_representation:

```
GOBBLET_REPRÉSENTATION = {1: ["▫", "◇", "◯", "□"],2: ["▪", "◆", "●", "■"],}
```

And when I made my test : `gobblet[1,3]`, it is supposed to be `["▫", "◇", "◯", "□"]` for `x` and  `"□"` for `y` but it shows me `["▪", "◆", "●", "■"]` for `x` and `"■"` for y all the time - same for `gobblet[1,2]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And the line `gobblet = [x,y]` doesn't do anything

Comment: After the first loop completes, `x` will be the last value. If you want to apply it multiple times, nest the remainder of the function in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of those

```
def formater_un_gobblet(gobblet):
  if gobblet == []:
      return None
  w = [1,2]
  for i in w:
      x = GOBBLET_REPRÉSENTATION[int(i)]
      if i == gobblet[0]:
        break
  z = [0,1,2,3]
  for l in z:
      y = x[int(l)]
      if l == gobblet[1]:
        break
  gobblet = [x,y]
  
  return (x,y)
```

or

```
def formater_un_gobblet2(gobblet):
  if gobblet == []:
      return None
  x= GOBBLET_REPRÉSENTATION[int(gobblet[0])]
  y=x[gobblet[1]]
  return (x,y)
```